# I need __closure__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just checked out this very interesting mindmap:

http://www.mindmeister.com/10510492/python-underscore

And I was wondering what some of the new ones mean, like `__code__` and `__closure__`. I googled around but nothing concrete. Does anyone know?

Comment: LOL @ subject, heheheheh

Answer (score 7):

From [What's New in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

The function attributes named `func_X` have been renamed to use the `__X__` form, freeing up these names in the function attribute namespace for user-defined attributes. To wit, `func_closure`, `func_code`, `func_defaults`, `func_dict`, `func_doc`, `func_globals`, `func_name` were renamed to `__closure__`, `__code__`, `__defaults__`, `__dict__`, `__doc__`, `__globals__`, `__name__`, respectively.

Basically, same old Python 2 stuff, fancy new Python 3000 name.

You can learn more about most of these in [PEP 232](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/)

Comment: I did try, didn't understand.

Comment: See the link in my answer for more details on the meaning.

Answer (score 6):

You actually have analogous fields in CPython 2.x:

```
>>> first = lambda x: lambda y: x
>>> f = first(2)
>>> type(f.func_code)
<type 'code'>
>>> map(type, f.func_closure)
[<type 'cell'>]
```

**Edit:** For more details on the meaning of these constructs please read about "user defined functions" and "code objects" [explained in the Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) chapter of the Python Reference.

Answer (score 4):

They used to be called

```
func_closure (now __closure__), func_code (now __code__)
```

(that should help googling).

A short explanation [from here](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6.2/reference/datamodel.html) below.

- func_closure: None or a tuple of cells that contain bindings for the function’s free variables (read-only)
- func_code: The code object
  representing the compiled function
  body (writable)

Answer (score 0):

These are Python's [special](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/special_class_methods.html) methods.