# Finding a list of all double-underscore variables?

Tags: python, metadata, conventions

Related: [What is the common header format of Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/python-what-is-the-common-header-format)

**Where can I find a list of all double-underscore variables that are commonly used in Python?**

In Python, variables starting and ending with double underscores are typically to store metadata or are built into the system.  For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__author__ = 'Michael0x2a'
__license__ = 'GPL'

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
```

I'm pretty certain `__author__` and `__license__` are pretty well known.  What other double-underscore metadata variables are there?  Is there a comprehensive list I can check somewhere?  Can I just make up my own, or are there a bunch of ones that have become de-facto standards that I should use?

Things like `__init__`, `__name__`, and `__doc__` are pretty much built into Python.  Are those the only reserved double-underscore variables?  Are there any more?  Is there some place I can get a list?

**[Edit]**
I was browsing and encountered another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609716/i-need-closure) that linked to a [mindmap](http://www.mindmeister.com/10510492/python-underscore) of a bunch of double-underscore variables.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to see magic names whether documented or not, go to the Lib directory and run:

```
egrep -oh '__[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*__' *.py | sort | uniq
```

That produces:

```
'__all__'
'__args__'
'__author__'
'__bases__'
'__builtin__'
'__builtins__'
'__cached__'
'__call__'
'__class__'
'__copy__'
'__credits__'
'__date__'
'__decimal_context__'
'__deepcopy__'
'__dict__'
'__doc__'
'__exception__'
'__file__'
'__flags__'
'__ge__'
'__getinitargs__'
'__getstate__'
'__gt__'
'__import__'
'__importer__'
'__init__'
'__ispkg__'
'__iter__'
'__le__'
'__len__'
'__loader__'
'__lt__'
'__main__'
'__module__'
'__mro__'
'__name__'
'__package__'
'__path__'
'__pkgdir__'
'__return__'
'__safe_for_unpickling__'
'__setstate__'
'__slots__'
'__temp__'
'__test__'
'__version__'
```

Comment: Interestingly, there are dozens of well-known dunder names that aren't in this list: __add__, __iadd__, __radd__, etc.

Comment: @NedBatchelder To get a more complete list, you need to recursively search __Lib__ *and* the directories below it:  ``find Lib -name '*.py' -exec egrep -oh '__[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*__' '{}' \; | sort | uniq``.  You'll see that there are *many* more names -- 256 of them on my Py27 checkout :)

Answer (score 15):

The complete list used by Python is given in the [Python Language Reference section 3, "Data model"](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html). Every other one is non-standard or used by third-party modules and is documented separately.

Comment: PEP 8 lists `__version__` as the only global variable for purely documentation purposes.

Comment: Interestingly, `__version__` does not appear in the linked language reference.

Comment: That's because it's not part of the language.