# A full list of special double-underscore properties in standard python libraries?

Tags: python, standard-library, double-underscore

Would anyone have a list of special python properties that begin and end with a double underscore with a brief explanation of their functionality?

Something along the following lines:

```
{
    "__slots__": "an iterable that restricts a set of admissible methods in a class",
    "__imul__": "*=",
    "__doc__": "docstring",
}
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names seems pretty authoritative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a list of all double-underscore variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920341/finding-a-list-of-all-double-underscore-variables)

Answer (score 3):

All that information is in the [Data Model](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) section of Python docs

Answer (score 2):

You can look [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) and [here (python docs)](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) for a list. But I don't know if they are really complete lists.